# When I call the C system() function, is the location of the new program's main() stack frame similar to the original program's main() stack frame?

Tags: c, memory, stack, system, buffer-overflow

I'm wondering if when I call the C `system()` function, the location of the new program's `main()` stack frame is similar to the original program's `main()` stack frame. Do anyone knows?

Below is "Program1" which calls `system()` to launch "Program2":

```c
int main() {
   int i;
   system("Program2");
}
```

Here is "Program2":

```c
int main() {
   int i;
}
```

I know that `main()` in "Program1" gets put on the stack, which means that the variable `i` will be on the stack. Let's say the address of this `i` in memory is `0x80000000`.

Now, when `system("Program2")` is called and launches "Program2", the `main()` function of this program gets put on a stack too; however, in a different memory space (as far as I am aware), so the `i` for "Program2" will be in memory too, but in a different memory space from the `i` in "Program1".

Even though both `i`'s will be in different memory spaces, will the address of `i` in "Program2" be similar or close to the address of `i` in "Program1" (`0x80000000`)?

For example, could it be something like `0x80000004` or close?

Comment: They are completely unrelated. They could be the same or different. But it doesn't matter since they are in different processes and, like you said, different address spaces.

Comment: Why don't you trying printing `&i` in both programs to see?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: "Programs" and functions do not get "put on the stack". Data gets put on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

In modern operating systems, each process has its own address space, using virtual memory, so the address of `i` in Program1 could be the same as the address of `i` in Program2, without referring to the same area of RAM.

Furthermore, 64-bit OSes use address space randomisation, giving the stacks of various processes or running instances of the same executables different addresses.

Finally, the variables `i` in both processes may actually have no address at all as they could live in registers or be optimized out at compile time.

Merely printing the address with `printf("%p\n", (void *)&i)` will force the compiler to at least temporarily allocate some space on the stack for `i`.

Comment: I followed Barmar's advice and did a `printf("%p\n", &i)` in both programs. The i's in both programs seems to have addresses that are fairly close to one another. Running it multiple times I get results like: 0xffd76521 vs 0xffc35465,      0xffe76521 vs 0xffb36461,     
  0xffd73551 vs 0xffe3b415,

Comment: @chrisjericho60120: the addresses vary from one run to another as expected because of *address space randomisation*... But they should be multiples of `sizeof(int)`, ie: 4.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if when I call the C system() function, the location of the new program's main() stack frame is similar to the original program's main() stack frame. Do anyone knows?

When you call the `system()` function, the program creates a new process by means of the `fork(2)` system call and the child process just `exec(2)`s a bourne shell, passing the string you pass as parameter to the shell to execute, then it `wait(2)`s for the child process to `exit(2)` and the shell exits too.  The single string passed as argument requires the bourne shell to interpret the command, and split it in program and argument list, so the answer to your question is **yes** the program is executed exactly the same as the original program you had first.